# Why are Broadcom such an issue for Ubuntu?

Tags: broadcom, modules

Is there a spesific reason why there are so many broadcom problems here on Ask Ubuntu, and on any other Ubuntu forum? What's the problem with Broadcom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a non free driver and thus can not be included into a vanilla Ubuntu. Problem with it is that there is not 1 driver but a lot of the models get their own specific driver. Look at the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/15811) to see what this means. I'll list 3 but there are many many more in the link:

- firmware-b43-installer - If you have BCM4306/3, BCM4311, BCM4318, BCM4321 or BCM4322 (only 14e4:432b)
- firmware-b43-lpphy-installer - If you have the BCM4312 (with Low-Power aka LP-PHY)
- firmware-b43legacy-installer - If you have the BCM4301, BCM4306/2 or BCM4306

The average Ubuntu user will have a bit of a problem since to *manually* install the correct driver the user needs to know exactly what model he has and what driver to use for that model.

---

But is this still a problem? The new additional driver tab we now have should fix all the issues: you will be prompted to install the correct driver:

[image]

So all the hassle should be avoidable nowadays.